# Two charts in a page not working, using Chart.js 3.1.1 cdn in Laravel 8.x framework

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I was using a single line chart in Laravel blade file with Chart.js 3.1.1 from cdn. I also have jQuery and Bootstrap imported to blade.  Everything was fine. Then I used another line chart in the same page. Then both the charts are not working now. I tried to debug in all possible ways. Not able to solve for now. There are no errors or warnings in chrome dev-console.

Any help is really appreciated.  I have added my page-source-code bits for reference.

```
<style>
  #usersMonthlyChart, #usersWeeklyChart{
   width:100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div>
      <canvas id="usersWeeklyChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div>
      <canvas id="usersMonthlyChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.1.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const weeklyLabels = ["Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
    const weeklyData = {
      labels: weeklyLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Users registered weekly',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(24, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(25, 99, 132)',
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,4],
      },
      {
        label: 'Users last seen weekly',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(12, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(10, 99, 132)',
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,4],
      }]
    };
    const weeklyConfig = {
      type: 'line',
      weeklyData,
      options: {}
    };
    var usersWeeklyChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('usersWeeklyChart'),
      weeklyConfig
    );
  </script>
  <script>
    const monthlyLabels = ["November","December","January","February","March","April"];
    const monthlyData = {
      labels: monthlyLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Users registered monthly',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,4],
      },
      {
        label: 'Users last seen monthly',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(100, 99, 132)',
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,4],
      }]
    };
    const monthlyConfig = {
      type: 'line',
      monthlyData,
      options: {}
    };
    var usersMonthlyChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('usersMonthlyChart'),
      monthlyConfig
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set data on options,
There is a wrong parameter on

```
const monthlyConfig = {
      type: 'line',
      monthlyData,
      options: {}
    };
```

try this

```
const weeklyConfig = {
      type: 'line',
      data: weeklyData,
      options: {}
    };
```

```
const monthlyConfig = {
      type: 'line',
      data: monthlyData,
      options: {}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ChartJS but I set up a JSFiddle and played around with your code.

I found that the config object you pass to `new Chart()` must have an element of name `data`.  So instead of:

```
const weeklyConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  weeklyData,
  options: {}
};
```

You must use:

```
const weeklyConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  data: weeklyData,
  options: {}
};
```

(for both charts, of course).

Here's a working snippet, the only changes I made are those described above.  Click "Run Snippet" to see it in action.

```js
const weeklyLabels = ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const weeklyData = {
  labels: weeklyLabels,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Users registered weekly',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(24, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(25, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
    },
    {
      label: 'Users last seen weekly',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(12, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(10, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
    }
  ]
};
const weeklyConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  data: weeklyData,
  options: {}
};
var usersWeeklyChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('usersWeeklyChart'),
  weeklyConfig
);

const monthlyLabels = ["November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April"];
const monthlyData = {
  labels: monthlyLabels,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Users registered monthly',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
    },
    {
      label: 'Users last seen monthly',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(100, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
    }
  ]
};
const monthlyConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  data: monthlyData,
  options: {}
};
var usersMonthlyChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('usersMonthlyChart'),
  monthlyConfig
);
```

```css
  #usersMonthlyChart,
  #usersWeeklyChart {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.1.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div>
      <canvas id="usersWeeklyChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div>
      <canvas id="usersMonthlyChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok. i found the answer. when using line chart in a blade using chartjs 3.1.1 and laravel 8.x, there are two cases.

case 1: if only one chart is present then, below code works. observe that data key is kind-of optional. value is required.

```
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {}
};
```

case 2: when using two charts, data key is required. if you dont use data key as shown below, charts wont appear on screen, no console errors, no way to debug.

```
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: myData,
  options: {}
};
```

for a cherry-cake-tip goto this github link.
[github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8979)